# Nouveau power management with Nvidia Tesla graphics

Tags: nvidia, power-management, nouveau

I have a MacBook Pro 13" Mid 2010 with a Nvidia GeForce 320M (NV50 family (Tesla) according to [this list](http://nouveau.freedesktop.org/wiki/CodeNames/)).

I installed Linux on this machine and wanted to use Nouveau as the video driver. Everything works fine except for power saving, which is very annoying because the MacBook get's pretty hot all the time (even under no load the GPU stays at 90°C in even without a graphical environment) and battery is very limited.

According to the `/sys/class/drm/card0/device/performance_level_*` information, the card should at least support clocking down the shader. I tried to change the performance_level to a lower value which only caused my graphics to stop working.

[This page](http://nouveau.freedesktop.org/wiki/PowerManagement/) suggests nouveau should be able to handle most of the power management features though.

1. Is there someone that got power management on a similar chip set-up and working?
2. Does anyone have more ideas on what to try? In particular I would like to make use of voltage regulation as I think that would work best.